# Select option on dropdown list for web ui testing automation in windows powershell

Tags: testing, scripting, powershell, automation, drop-down-menu

Sorry if this is too easy of a question, but I'm fairly new to Windows Powershell and all of the tutorials I've looked at for dropdown lists show you how to display one to the user.

Anyway what I am trying to do is test my web application using Powershell. I need to change a dropdownlist to a specific choice, I can use the value or index to do this it doesn't matter to me.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the easiest way to do it was to just set the value of the control to the index I wanted like this:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("mywebsite")
$ie.visible = $true
$doc = $ie.document
$listbox = $doc.getElementByID(listboxID)
$listbox.value = 1
```

This selects the first value in the list box. I have no idea how to tell what that value is if you don't already know it. Or select based off of text but I don't need that.

Comment: You can select the value based on text. E.g. if you have a dropdown with a choice of colors you can do:

$listbox.value = "Blue"

Comment: Text values are case sensitive by the way.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [WatiN](http://watin.org/) [from PowerShell](http://poshcode.org/2434)?

Comment: I'm looking at it, Do I have to download it or is it something I can use with basic powershell?

Comment: You have to download WatiN from the first link and the PowerWatin script from the second link.  But it will make testing easier as WatiN takes care of a lot of the browser specific stuff.