# Select option from dropdown

Tags: html, powershell, internet-explorer, automation

I'm working on some automation and I came across one dropdown where I'm having an issue to select an option.

Only way, I was able to get the element is trough `IHTMLDocument3`:

```
$dropdown = $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByName("searchTypeChoice")
```

This is limiting my options how to select an option, since I can't use

```
.Options.Selected = $true
```

or anything else. I found these questions:

- [Powershell..select drop down menu from web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150397/powershell-select-drop-down-menu-from-web-page)
- [Select option on dropdown list for web ui testing automation in windows powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379922/select-option-on-dropdown-list-for-web-ui-testing-automation-in-windows-powershe)

This is the element I'm talking about:

[image: Dropdown]

Do you have any suggestions? Or maybe another method how to get the dropdown in other way?

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate the options, filter the one you want to select by its value (or inner text), then select it:

```
$dropdown.Options |
  Where-Object { $_.Value -eq 1 } |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Selected = $true }
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick replay, but it doiesn't work. I tried both (Value and InnerText) but selected option stayed at default one which is the first, but I need second.