# How to change choice dropdown web page on internet explorer

Tags: powershell

I use powershell and IE. The goal is to modify the choice in a drop-down list present on a web page in IE.

Currently, my beginning of script allows to:
- connect to the desired site
- go to another page (tab on the site)

---

Here is my powershell code:

```
cls
$login = "user"
$mdp = "mot_de_passe"

$url = "https://site.domaine.fr/index.php"
$url2 = "https://site.domaine.fr/projets/ocean/#orphelin"

$ie = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($url2) ; while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -s 4} 

$ie.Document.getElementById("HeaderLogin").value=$login
$ie.Document.getElementByID("HeaderPassword").value=$mdp
$ie.Document.getElementById("HeaderLoginButton").click()

start-sleep 3

$ie.navigate($url2) ; while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -s 10}
```

---

The next objective is to:
modify the choice of the drop-down list

Here is the code of the page:

```
<select name="t_Imp_length" aria-controls="t_Imp" class="">
Afficher 
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="-1">Afficher Tout</option>
</select>
```

---

The last point to be discussed later:
- copy the present table into an excel file

Comment: In english, please

Comment: I've no idea what you wrote in comment, but since you've translated your question it may be reopened soon (after some people accept to reopen it)

Comment: I have made the necessary modifications

Comment: I fail to see an attempt to solve your issue in the question, so it may be hard to reopen it, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41482917/select-option-from-dropdown) may help you